# How to wrap a generator with a filter?

Tags: python, generator

I have a series of connected generators and I want to create a filter that can be used to wrap one of the generators. This filter wrapper should take a generator and a function as parameters. If a data item in the incoming stream does not pass the requirements of the filter, it should be passed downstream to the next generator without going through the wrapped generator. I have made a working example here that should make it more clear as to what I am trying to achieve:

```
import functools

is_less_than_three = lambda x : True if x < 3 else False

def add_one(numbers):
    print("new generator created")
    for number in numbers:
        yield number + 1

def wrapper(generator1, filter_):
    @functools.wraps(generator1)
    def wrapped(generator2):
        for data in generator2:
            if filter_(data):
                yield from generator1([data])
            else:
                yield data
    return wrapped

add_one_to_numbers_less_than_three = wrapper(add_one, is_less_than_three)
answers = add_one_to_numbers_less_than_three(range(6))
for answer in answers:
    print(answer)

#new generator created
#1
#new generator created
#2
#new generator created
#3
#3
#4
#5
```

The problem with this is that it requires creating a new generator for each data item. There must be a better way? I have also tried using itertools.tee and splitting the generator, but this causes memory problems when the generators yield values at different rates (they do). How can I accomplish what the above code does without re-creating generators and without causing memory problems?

**edited to add background information below**

As input I will receive large video streams. The video streams may or may not end (could be a webcam). Users are able to choose which image processing steps are carried out on the video frames, thus the order and number of functions will change. Subsequently, the functions should be able to take each other's outputs as inputs.

I have accomplished this by using a series of generators. The input:output ratio of the generators/functions is variable - it could be 1:n, 1:1, or n:1 (for example, extracting several objects (subimages) from an image to be processed separately).

Currently these generators take a few parameters that are repeated among them (not DRY) and I am trying to decrease the number of parameters by refactoring them into separate generators or wrappers. One of the more difficult ones is a filter on the data stream to determine whether or not a function should be applied to the frame (the function could be cpu-intensive and not needed on all frames).

The number of parameters makes the usage of the function more difficult for the user to understand. It also makes it more difficult for me in that whenever I want to make a change to one of the common parameters, I have to edit it for all functions.

**edit2 renamed function to generator in example code to make it more clear**

**edit3 the solution**
Thank you @Blckknght. This can be solved by creating an infinite iterator that passes the value of a local variable to the generator. I modified my example slightly to change add_one to a 1:n generator instead of a 1:1 generator to show how this solution can also work for 1:n generators.

```
import functools

is_less_than_three = lambda x : True if x < 3 else False

def add_one(numbers):
    print("new generator created")
    for number in numbers:
        if number == 0:
            yield number - 1
            yield number
        else:
            yield number

def wrapper(generator1, filter_):
    @functools.wraps(generator1)
    def wrapped(generator2):
        local_variable_passer = generator1(iter(lambda: data, object()))
        for data in generator2:
            if filter_(data):
                next_data = next(local_variable_passer)
                if data == 0:
                    yield next_data
                    next_data = next(local_variable_passer)
                    yield next_data
                else:
                    yield next_data
            else:
                yield data
    return wrapped

add_one_to_numbers_less_than_three = wrapper(add_one, is_less_than_three)
answers = add_one_to_numbers_less_than_three(range(6))
for answer in answers:
    print(answer)

#new generator created
#-1
#0
#1
#2
#3
#3
#4
#5
```

Comment: Does the generator you want to wrap around always yield one output value for each input value? Or could there be a variable number of outputs? I'm sure you could make this work if it's 1:1, but I'm not sure there's an easy way to go about managing the flow control if can yield a variable number.

Comment: @Blckknght wait, what do you mean exactly? Anyway, I'm not sure if there is any way you can get passed this trade-off. To me, it looks like just re-calling the generator function is the least-bad alternative, if `tee` consumes too much memory.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to "pass" *individual items* in and out of a generator *expecting multiple items*? Why isn't ``add_one`` a function expecting a single item?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi because the wrapper has to either produce the item or the item produced by the generator it is wrapping, this is the ugly hack that is required if you don't want to consume auxiliary memory with a `itertools.tee` approach. It's ugly, but I can't find any way around it.

Comment: On further thought, I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't follow. ``add_one`` should just be ``number: return number + 1`` (and the wrapper doing ``yield function(data)``). If the transformation may or may not *produce* multiple items, it should be ````number: yield number + 1````. There is no need to take more than one number.

Comment: The connections can be 1:n, 1:1, or n:1. Furthermore, the number of generators and ordering between the generators is often dynamic, making the use of coroutines difficult. @MisterMiyagi As for why I am using generators expecting generators instead of functions expecting single values, it is because I am dealing with processing large video streams. I could replace many of the generators with single value functions, but then I would also need to create specialized looper functions that take functions, parameters, decorators, and decorator parameters. I feel like that would get even messier?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a clear, unambiguous problem statement. It is currently unclear what your requirements are.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added some background information, I hope it helps. By the way your answer from earlier did not help with my particular problem, but it was very detailed and might help someone with a similar problem who finds this post. I think it would be great to post it here if you still have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you have a stream of video frames, and you're trying to create a pipeline of processing functions that modify the stream. Different processing functions might change the number of frames, so a single input frame could result in multiple output frames, or multiple input frames could be consumed before a single output frame is produced. Some functions might be 1:1, but that's not something you can count on.

Your current implementation uses generator functions for all the processing. The output function iterates on the chain, and each processing step in the pipeline requests frames from the one before it using iteration.

The function you're trying to write right now is a sort of selective bypass. You want for some frames (those meeting some condition) to get passed in to some already existing generator function, but other frames to skip over the processing and just go directly into the output. Unfortunately, that's probably not possible to do with Python generators. The iteration protocol is just not sophisticated enough to support it.

First off, it *is* possible to do this for 1:1 with generators, but you can't easily generalize to `n`:1 or 1:`n` cases. Here's what it might look like for 1:1:

```
def selective_processing_1to1(processing_func, condition, input_iterable):
    processing_iterator = processing_func(iter(lambda: input_value, object()))
    for input_value in input_iterator:
        if condition(input_value):
            yield next(processing_iterator)
        else:
            yield input_value
```

There's a lot of work being done in the `processing_iterator` creation step. By using the two-argument form of `iter` with a `lambda` function and a sentinel object (that will never be yielded), I'm creating an infinite iterator that always yields the current value of the local variable `input_value`. Then I pass that iterator it to the `processing_func` function. I can selectively call `next` on the generator object if I want to apply the processing the filter represents to the current value, or I can just yield the value myself without processing it.

But because this only works on one frame at a time, it won't do for `n`:1 or 1:`n` filters (and I don't even want to think about `m`:`n` kinds of scenarios).

A "peekable" iterator that lets you see what the next value is going to be before you iterate onto it might let you support a limited form of selective filtering for `n`:1 processes (that is, where a possibly-variable `n` input frames go into one output frame). The limitation is that you can only do the selective filtering on the first of the `n` frames that is going to be consumed by the processing, the others will get taken without you getting a chance to check them first. Maybe that's good enough?

Anyway, here's what that looks like:

```
_sentinel = object()
class PeekableIterator:
    def __init__(self, input_iterable):
        self.iterator = iter(input_iterable)
        self.next_value = next(self.iterator, _sentinel)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.next_value != _sentinel:
            return_value = self.next_value
            self.next_value = next(self.iterator, _sentinel)
            return return_value
        raise StopIteration

    def peek(self):                 # this is not part of the iteration protocol!
        if self.next_value != _sentinel:
            return self.next_value
        raise ValueError("input exhausted")

def selective_processing_Nto1(processing_func, condition, input_iterable):
    peekable = PeekableIterator(input_iterable)
    processing_iter = processing_func(peekable)
    while True:
        try:
            value = peekable.peek()
            print(value, condition(value))
        except ValueError:
            return
        try:
            yield next(processing_iter) if condition(value) else next(peekable)
        except StopIteration:
            return
```

This is as good as we can practically do when the processing function is a generator. If we wanted to do more, such as supporting 1:`n` processing, we'd need some way to know how large the `n` was going to be, so we could get that many values before deciding if we will pass on the next input value or not. While you could write a custom class for the processing that would report that, it is probably less convenient than just calling the processing function repeatedly as you do in the question.

Comment: wow, that infinite iterator is very cool! I might be able to get that to work for my 1:n cases as well by ensuring that the 1:n generators include in their output some kind of flag signaling how many more items they will yield. For my n:1 cases, maybe I could transform them to 1:1 by having them yield messages signaling that they are in the middle of processing. I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to report back regarding this. This worked great for my use case! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The architecture is a conditional map - as such, each item must be mapped individually. This means the `function` should receive *one* number, not *many* numbers.

---

As long as there is a stateless 1:1 connection, use a *function* instead of a generator.

```
def add_one(number):  # takes one number
    return number + 1  # provides one number

def conditional_map(function, condition):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapped(generator):
        return (
            function(item) if condition(item)
            else item for item in generator
        )
    return wrapped

for answer in conditional_map(add_one, lambda x: x < 3)(range(6)):
    print(answer)
```

---

If data must be passed to a stateful "generator", it is a coroutine and should be designed as such. This means that `yield` is used both to *receive* and provide data.

```
from itertools import count

def add_increment(start=0):
    # initially receive data
    number = yield
    for increment in count(start):
        # provide and receive data
        number = yield number + increment
```

Since this is still a 1:1 connection, it can be used with the previous `conditional_map`.

```
mapper = add_increment()
next(mapper)  # prime the coroutine - this could be done with a decorator

for answer in conditional_map(mapper.send, lambda x: x < 3)(range(6)):
    print(answer)
```

---

If 1:n connections are needed, expect to receive a generator for *each* input.

```
def add_some(number):  # takes one number
    yield number - 1
    yield number
    yield number + 1

def conditional_map(function, condition):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapped(generator):
        for data in generator:
            if filter_(data):
                yield from function(data)  # passes one *one* item
            else:
                yield data
    return wrapped
```

If a stateful 1:n connection is required, a coroutine that produces a generator/iterable can be used.

```
def add_increments(start=0):
    # initially receive data
    number = yield
    for increment in count(start):
        # provide and receive data
        number = yield (number + increment + i for i in (-1, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and code examples. Your first example has given me an idea. Perhaps instead of generators being linked together through being passed to each other as parameters, the generators should be replaced with wrappers that take generators and functions and create new generators. I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking. I just re-created my original example but passed uninitialized generators instead of initialized generators. Still had the same problem of course. I think none of these methods will work well for my situation. See my comment on the original post for why.

Answer (score 1):

It really seems like you all are making this too complicated.
If you think of a data processing pipeline as

```
    source -> transform -> filter -> sink
```

where source, transform, filter are all generators.
this is similar to Unix pipelines

```
    cat f | tr 'a' 'A' | grep 'word' > /dev/null
```

then you can see how a pipeline works (conceptually).
One big difference is that Unix pipelines push data, where with Python generators you pull data.

Using some of your functions:

```
# this is a source
def add_one(numbers):
    print("new generator created")
    # this is the output that becomes the next function's input
    for number in numbers:
        yield number + 1  

# this is a transform
def filter(input, predicate):
    for item in input:
       if predicate(item):
            yield item

# this is the sink
def save(input, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for item in input:
            f.write(item)
```

To put the pipeline of generators together in python you start with the source, then pass it to a transform or filter as a parameter that can be iterated over. Of course each of the generators has a yield statement. Finally the outermost function is the sink and it consumes the values while it iterates.
It looks like this. You can see how the predicate function is passed to the filter function in addition to the "source" of its data.

```
# now run the pipeline
save(filter(add_one(range(20), is_less_than_three), 'myfile')
```

Some find that this looks awkward but if you think of mathematical notation it is easier. I am sure you have seen `f(g(x))` which is exactly the same notation.
You could also write it as:

```
save(filter(add_one(range(20), 
            is_less_than_three), 
     'myfile')
```

which shows better how the parameters are used.

To recap
The pipeline is a generator. In this case it won't have a generator as its source. It may have non-generator input such as a list of numbers (your example), or create them some other way such as reading a file.

Transform generators always have a generator for their source, and they yield output to their "sink". In other words a transform acts like a sink to its source and like a source to its sink.

The sink is final part of a pipeline is a sink that just iterates over its source input. It consumes its input and doesn't yield any output. Its job is to consume the items, by processing, saving printing or whatever.

A transform is a m to n function that for m inputs produces n outputs, meaning it can filter out some inputs and not pass them, or product multiple outputs by creating new items. An example might be transforming a video stream from 60fps to 30fps. For every two input frames it produces one output frame.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! In this case, your filter function is deleting all numbers greater than three from the stream. How could we keep those numbers and pull them to the sink without modifying the internals of the transform? For example, what if we wanted to add one to numbers less than three, but keep all other numbers the same?

Comment: The reasonable way would be to write a single transform to just add one to numbers less than three. No filtering is required if you want the sink to see all the numbers.